# Lambda function's input's parameter in Scala

Tags: scala, lambda, types

I'm using `addChangeListener` from the Java Swing API in my Scala program. The compiler of ScalaFiddle indicates an error in the following code :

```
spinner_1.addChangeListener(e => {
              ...
})
```

> error: missing parameter type
>         spinner_1.addChangeListener(e => {

I tried to write `e : ChangeListener`, but it didn't solve this problem. I didn't find something useful for that in Scala's documentation.

How could I deal with it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works in [Scala 2.12](https://www.scala-lang.org/news/2.12.0/#lambda-syntax-for-sam-types). But if you have to use older version like 2.11, you can use implicit conversion. Here is an example:

```
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane
import javax.swing.event.{ChangeEvent, ChangeListener}

implicit def convertToChangeListener(f: ChangeEvent => Unit): ChangeListener =
  new ChangeListener {
    override def stateChanged(e: ChangeEvent): Unit = f.apply(e)
  }

val listener: ChangeListener = (e: ChangeEvent)  => ...

new JTabbedPane().addChangeListener(listener)
```